# Finding the change of a basis from 1 matrix to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I know how to convert a given Basis B to a standard basis.
I know how to find a coordinate vector with respect to B given the standard basis.

But how do I find the change of basis from a Matrix to another Matrix? These two set of vectors, write them as a matrix.
B1 = {[-1,1,-1], [1,0,2], [-2,5,0]} 
B2 = {[-2,1,3], [2,0,1], [4,1,-1]}

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two basis $\left( v_{1}, \ldots , v_{n}\right)$ and $\left( w_{1}, \ldots , w_{n}\right)$. Suppose a vector $v$ is written as linear combination of the first set, i.e. $v = \sum _{i=1}^{n} a_{i} v_{i}$. Then write every element of the first basis as a linear combination of elements of the second, i.e. $v_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_{ij}w_{j}$ Then you have $v= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{ij}a_{i}\right) w_{j}$. So the recipe is the following:

1. build the matrix in which the column i gives the coordinates of $v_{i}$ with respect to $\left( w_{1}, \ldots , w_{n}\right)$
2. consider the column vector containing the coordinates of $v$ with respect to $\left( v_{1}, \ldots , v_{n}\right)$
3. multiply them and you have the new coordinates